# apache RewriteRule and proxypass

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am in the process of setting up a jira server and will use apache to be a proxy to the tomcat service. I have my apache setup 90% completed but can't workout the final configuration. The goal is to have users be able to access the FQDN, the alias or the fully qualified alias but the URL is always rewritten to the DNS alias. e.g user browses to:

```
http://jira.domian.com rewrite to https://jira

http://nbsrvjira-07v rewrite to https://jira

http://nbsrvjira-07v.diasemi.com rewrite to https://jira
```

All the above work however the below fail:

```
https://jira.domian.com rewrite to https://jira 

https://nbsrvjira-07v rewrite to https://jira

https://nbsrvjira-07v.diasemi.com rewrite to https://jira
```

Unless a specific URL is used it will cause issue within the application, the apache configuration is below:

The http to https redirect:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  nbsrvjira-07v.domain.com
  ServerAlias jira-test jira-test.domain.com
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/nbsrvjira-07v.domain.com_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/nbsrvjira-07v.domain.com_access.log" combined
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://jira-test/ [noescape,last,redirect=302]
  </VirtualHost>
```

The https to proxy pass:

```
VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  nbsrvjira-07v.domain.com
    ServerAlias jira jira.domain.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/nbsrvjira-07v.domain.com_error.log"
    ServerSignature Off
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/nbsrvjira-07v.domain.com_access.log" combined
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/nbsrvjira-07v.domain.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/nbsrvjira-07v.domain.com.key"
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8080/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=300
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    </VirtualHost>
```

I have tried various rewrite rules within the https configuration but none seem to work. Can someone help?

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set up more than one VirtualHost for *:443 where one or more will just redirect to https://jira and only one will act as https://jira and contain the proxying? Just a guess.

Comment: I did try that but it didn't help and I got a duplicate vhost warning.

Comment: Ok. Strange that you got duplicate hosts. Did you really use different ServerName in the different hosts?

Comment: I always set the servername to     ServerName  nbsrvjira-07v.domain.com

Comment: I was thinking you should only use ServerName nbsrvjira-07v.domain.com and ServerAlias jira on one "main" *.443 host. That host would look like the one in your question. Then set up three other *:443 hosts with ServerName https://jira.domian.com, https://nbsrvjira-07v and https://nbsrvjira-07v.diasemi.com respectively. These three host should only have rewrite rules to lead to the "main" host.